# Provide parameter for rake in ruby

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a rake task that uses a parameter on the command line like that:

```
rake sunspot:reindex[, MyModel]
```

(Yes, the direct comma behind the bracket is correct.)

How do I specify the same rake command from within Ruby?

Some attempts that don't work:

```
Rake::Task['sunspot:reindex'].execute("[, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging]")
Rake::Task['sunspot:reindex'].execute([nil, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging])
Rake::Task['sunspot:reindex[, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging]'].execute
```

Some other suggestions what I could try else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `invoke` instead of `execute`:

```
Rake::Task['sunspot:reindex'].invoke(nil, ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging)
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found this nice answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task/825832#825832

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the command as a system process. You have several alternatives

```
klass = Model

`rake sunspot:reindex #{klass}`
%x(rake sunspot:reindex #{klass})
system "rake", "sunspot:reindex", klass
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But what I would like to find out is how to set parameters by using Rake::Task ... I am just curious.