# How can I pass named arguments to a Rake task?

Tags: ruby, arguments, rake, task, named-parameters

Is there a way to pass named arguments to a Rake task without using environment variables?

I am aware that Rake tasks can accept arguments in two formats:

**Environment Variables**

```
$ rake my_task foo=bar
```

This creates an environment variable with the name `foo` and the value `bar` that can be accessed in the Rake task `my_task` by `ENV['foo']`.

**Rake Task Arguments**

```
$ rake my_task['foo','bar']
```

This passes the values `foo` and `bar` to the first two task arguments (if they are defined). If `my_task` were defined as:

```
task :my_task, :argument_1, :argument_2
```

then `argument_1` would have the value `foo` and `argument_2` would have the value `bar`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can say things like this:

```
rake some_task -- --arg=value
```

And then, inside your task, `ARGV` will be

```
[ 'some_task', '--arg=value' ]
```

so you could use [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html) (or some other option parser) to unpack `ARGV` just like in any old CLI script; the funny looking `--` is necessary to keep rake from trying to parse `--arg=like` as a rake switch.

You're probably better off with the standard environment variable approach, it isn't as ugly as all the `--` stuff and it is the usual way of passing arguments to rake tasks.