# ActiveRecord: List columns in table from console

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I know that you can ask ActiveRecord to list tables in console using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

Is there a command that would list the columns in a given table?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

This will list the column_names from a table

```
Model.column_names
e.g. User.column_names
```

Comment: You could also run something like `Model.columns` to get more info about the columns including database config data.

Comment: Great! Using `Model.columns` provides all the information for a table through ActiveRecord. Crucially for me it was the only and easiest way to gain confidence in what my __primary key__ really was at the database level.

Comment: You could always use Model.primary_key, which gives you the name of the primary key according to rails. (This will be 'id' unless it's declared in the model as something else).

Answer (score 67):

This gets the columns, not just the column names and uses ActiveRecord::Base::Connection, so no models are necessary.  Handy for quickly outputting the structure of a db.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table_name|
  puts table_name
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns(table_name).each do |c| 
    puts "- #{c.name}: #{c.type} #{c.limit}"
  end
end
```

Sample output:  http://screencast.com/t/EsNlvJEqM

Comment: In rails 3.2, doing it this way somehow doesn't set the `primary` attribute correctly (all columns have `primary=nil`). It is set correctly with the `Model.columns` method suggested by srt32.

Comment: This is the right answer. There is no requirement to have a model. Not every table has a model.  "has_many_and_belongs_to"

Comment: To provide a list sorted by table name, use: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.sort.each

Answer (score 23):

Using rails three you can just type the model name:

```
> User
gives:
User(id: integer, name: string, email: string, etc...)
```

In rails four, you need to establish a connection first:

```
irb(main):001:0> User
=> User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)
irb(main):002:0> User.connection; nil #call nil to stop repl spitting out the connection object (long)
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> User
User(id: integer, name: string, email: string, etc...)
```

Comment: OP just wants the column names.

Comment: Perhaps. But not necessarily. It is an alternative way of getting them with extra info that is sometimes helpful when listing columns from console

Comment: This is also a useful method to know, IMO. @Yule - does this query the schema/migrations code etc. or does it query the DB? The reason I ask is I was experiencing a mismatch between my schema and what actually was in the DB (one migration glitched), so specifically I needed to be sure I was seeing what was actually in the table.

Comment: @Andrew it queries the DB (hence the need to establish a connection in rails 4)

Answer (score 8):

complementing this useful information, for example using rails console o rails dbconsole:

Student is my Model, using rails console:

```
$ rails console
> Student.column_names
 => ["id", "name", "surname", "created_at", "updated_at"] 

> Student
 => Student(id: integer, name: string, surname: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Other option using SQLite through Rails:

```
$ rails dbconsole

sqlite> .help

sqlite> .table
ar_internal_metadata  relatives             schools             
relationships         schema_migrations     students 

sqlite> .schema students
CREATE TABLE "students" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar, "surname" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);
```

Finally for more information.

```
sqlite> .help
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

If you are comfortable with SQL commands,  you can enter your app's folder and run `rails db`, which is a brief form of `rails dbconsole`. It will enter the shell of your database, whether it is sqlite or mysql.

Then, you can query the table columns using sql command like:

```
pragma table_info(your_table);
```

Comment: For mySQL use `describe your_table;`, not perfect but works

Answer (score 2):

You can run `rails dbconsole` in you command line tool to open sqlite console. Then type in `.tables` to list all the tables and `.fullschema` to get a list of all tables with column names and types.

Comment: You can use online database console (gem [activeadmin-sqlpage](https://github.com/oklas/activeadmin-sqlpage)) as describerd in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43159348/2969544) if you use active admin.

Answer (score 2):

- To list the columns in a table I usually go with this:
  `Model.column_names.sort`.
  `i.e. Orders.column_names.sort`

  Sorting the column names makes it easy to find what you are looking for.
- For more information on each of the columns use this:
  `Model.columns.map{|column| [column.name, column.sql_type]}.to_h`.

This will provide a nice hash.
for example:

```
{
   id => int(4),
   created_at => datetime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more compact format, and less typing just:

```
Portfolio.column_types
```

Comment: Does not exist in rails 5+

Comment: The answer doesn't state that, and the question is tagged Rails 3 @Pak...

Comment: @SebastianPalma I know, but as this is a well-referenced question such comments are imo helpful for people looking for answers, fast. The tag was probably chosen during the initial write-up but the question is quite generic.

Answer (score 0):

I am using rails 6.1 and have built a simple rake task for this.

You can invoke this from the cli using `rails db:list[users]` if you want a simple output with field names. If you want all the details then do `rails db:list[users,1]`.

I constructed this from this question [How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task) about passing command line arguments to rake tasks. I also built on @aaron-henderson's answer above.

```rb
# run like `rails db:list[users]`, `rails db:list[users,1]`, `RAILS_ENV=development rails db:list[users]` etc
namespace :db do
  desc "list fields/details on a model"
  task :list, [:model, :details] => [:environment] do |task, args|
    model = args[:model]
    if !args[:details].present?
      model.camelize.constantize.column_names.each do |column_name|
        puts column_name
      end
    else
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table_name|
        next if table_name != model.underscore.pluralize
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns(table_name).each do |c|
          puts "Name: #{c.name} | Type: #{c.type} | Default: #{c.default} | Limit: #{c.limit} | Precision: #{c.precision} | Scale: #{c.scale} | Nullable: #{c.null} "
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```