# Use rails console sql query strings to learn sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

Using the [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) from inside the [rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console) I'm able to easily and sensibly get: the first item's style's retail price:

```
[25] pry(main)> Item.first.style.retail_price
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Style Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "styles".* FROM "styles" WHERE "styles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<BigDecimal:7fe7a6bc7678,'0.6E2',9(27)>
```

I read in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22752777/2909897) that I can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` to run raw sql commands. I was expected to get something that looks sort of like '60.0' back because `Item.first.style.retail_price.to_s #=> "60.0"` Instead a I get some sort of array with a hash inside it:

```
[26] pry(main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1; SELECT  "styles".* FROM "styles" WHERE "styles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]')

   (0.2ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1; SELECT  "styles".* FROM "styles" WHERE "styles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> [{"id"=>1, "size"=>"M", "color"=>"Purple", "status"=>"sellable", "price_sold"=>nil, "sold_at"=>nil, "style_id"=>1, "created_at"=>"2017-02-04 04:47:09.415828", "updated_at"=>"2017-02-04 04:47:09.415828", "clearance_batch_id"=>nil, 0=>1, 1=>"M", 2=>"Purple", 3=>"sellable", 4=>nil, 5=>nil, 6=>1, 7=>"2017-02-04 04:47:09.415828", 8=>"2017-02-04 04:47:09.415828", 9=>nil}]
```

Also when I try to the same query string is [`rails db`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10172323/2909897) I get a syntax error:

```
rails db
SQLite version 3.14.0 2016-07-26 15:17:14
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1; SELECT  "styles".* FROM "styles" WHERE "styles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]];
1|M|Purple|sellable|||1|2017-02-04 04:47:09.415828|2017-02-04 04:47:09.415828|
Error: near "[["id", 1]": syntax error
sqlite>
```

3 questions:

1. What string does `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` need to return an expected result that looks something like 60.0?
2. What string does `rails db` need?
3. What is the general pattern of how to translate the sql string that the  `rails console` gives me into a raw sql query string that would work with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` and `rails db`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one field from one realtion, you have to specify it in the `select` clause in SQL. Something like this

```
SELECT styles.retail_price FROM styles WHERE styles.id = 1
```

In this case, you obtain just the `retail_price` but in an array if you use rails's `execute` method. If you want just the single value use `select_value` method, not `execute`. Like

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value("SELECT styles.retail_price FROM styles WHERE styles.id = 1")
```

In the sqlite3 terminal you obtain a syntax error because of this `[["id", 1]]`. That's a rails/applicative-level stuff used for prepared statements but is not valid SQL. You should just substitute the id like I did.