# Rails: Get PostgresQL table column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have a table of varying PostgresQL data types:

```
  CREATE TABLE users (
    name varchar(255),
    age int4
  );
```

When I get that table's columns through the model, the sql_type returned is different than what I entered:

```
User.columns.first.name #=> "name"
User.columns.first.sql_type #=> "character varying"
User.columns.last.name #=> "age"
User.columns.last.sql_type #=> "integer"
```

How can I get the original types? In this case it would be `varchar(255)` and `int4`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575970/activerecord-list-columns-in-table-from-console ... The answer just below the "accepted" answer has a great code block that spits out all the details about your columns that I just ran in my console and it output what I believe would be the data you seek.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky That returns what I have above. For example, it returns `integer` rather than `int4`

Comment: I do see what you mean, the limit attribute appears to only apply for string/varchar fields and not ints.

Comment: `varchar` and `character varying` are exactly the same thing, so are `int4` and `integer`. Connect to your database with the `psql` CLI tool and say `\d users`, you'll see no `varchar` or `int4` in sight.

Comment: @muistooshort `my_mind == blown`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html):

> **8.3. Character Types**
>   [...]
>   The notations `varchar(n)` and `char(n)` are aliases for `character varying(n)` and `character(n)`, respectively.

So the real type name is `character varying` but you can use `varchar` if you want. Similarly for [integer types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT):

> **8.1.1. Integer Types**
>   [...]
>   SQL only specifies the integer types `integer` (or `int`), `smallint`, and `bigint`. The type names `int2`, `int4`, and `int8` are extensions, which are also used by some other SQL database systems.

So you can say `int4` if you want but internally that's `integer`.

You can even check what the database really thinks using `psql`:

```
=> create table users (name varchar(255), age int4);
CREATE TABLE
=> \d users
            Table "public.users"
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------+------------------------+-----------
 name   | character varying(255) | 
 age    | integer                |
```

No `varchar` or `int4` in sight, just `character varying` and `integer`. You can use the aliases when creating tables but the database will always talk to you using the standard types.

You'll find similar shenanigans going on if you use `decimal(m,n)` (an alias for `numeric(m,n)`), `timestamp` (really `timestamp without time zone`), etc.