# Need to DRY up my rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Basically Im running a rake task to update the "notes" field in my rails 3 app. Currently I have my task set up as follows:

```
desc "Update notes"
  task :get_notes => :environment do
      Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["categories like ?", "%" + '123456' + "%"]).each do |product|
      old_note = product.notes
      notes = old_note + ", <new note>"
      product.update_attribute(:notes, notes)
    end
```

The problem is I have about 250 unique categories to update with 250 unique notes, so I've basically just copied this over 250 times in my task. How can I more efficiently accomplish this? (This is just a one time thing, but I would like to know how to better do it for future issues such as this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a function:

```
  def add_note(category, note)
    Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["categories like ?", "%" + category + "%"]).each do |product|
    old_note = product.notes
    if old_note != nil
    notes = old_note + note
  else notes = note
  end
    product.update_attribute(:notes, notes)
  end
end
```

and just called the function with each of the unique variables:

```
desc "Update note"
  task :get_notes => :environment do
    add_note('7818797', "<note>")
end
end
```

Comment: If you have an array of category ids and an array of notes you could use the Array [zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) method to join them together and call add_note inside the each block.

Answer (score 2):

take this: [How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

```
task :get_notes, [:category] => :environment do |t, args|
  Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["categories like ?", "%#{args[:category]}%"]).each do |product|
  old_note = product.notes
  notes = old_note + ", <new note>"
  product.update_attribute(:notes, notes)
end
```

run as: `rake get_notes[123456]`