# Is it possible to send arguments to `rake cucumber` without using environment variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake

I see that it is possible to pass arguments to a rake task:

```
task :task_name, :arg_name do |t, args|
```

What I'd like to do is pass arguments into a cucumber rake task:

```
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:tags => 'db:test:prepare'}) do |t, args|
  t.cucumber_opts = ['--tags', #args?]
end
```

Is this sort of thing possible? This way I could do:

```
rake cucumber:tags['tag1', 'tag2', ...]
```

And have it run only those tags. Most sources say to use an environment variable, which I have done, but I'd prefer to just provide the arguments the "right" way.

Comment: this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task

Comment: No it isn't. This question is specific to Cucumber, you cannot add arguments to Cucumber rake tasks like you can in the answer to that question.

Comment: Gotcha. Would it be possible to write your own rake tasks that wrap the cucumber ones ?

Answer (score 5):

You can get it to work by doing something like this:

```
task :task_name, :arg1 do |t, args|
  Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:run) do |t|
    t.cucumber_opts = "--format pretty --tags @#{args[:arg1]}"
  end
  Rake::Task[:run].invoke()
end
```

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this would be through environment variables like so: `rake cucumber:tags TAGS=tag1,tag2` and then in your rake task just parse `ARGV`.

```
tags = ARGV[1].gsub(/.+=/, '')

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:tags => 'db:test:prepare'}) do |t, args|
  t.cucumber_opts = ['--tags', tags]
end
```

You can also make it more flexible like this

```
tags_index = ARGV.index {|a| a.start_with?('TAGS') }
tags = ARGV[tags_index].gsub(/.+=/, '')
```

but probably you'd be better of with something like [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html).