# Can I pass an argument to rake db:seed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rakefile, seeding

Part of my `seeds.rb` loads a lot of data into the database. I want to be able to selectively load this data. E.g.

```
$ rake db:seed
```

or

```
$rake db:seed[0]
```

would just load the necessary data to run the site, while

```
$ rake db:seed[1]
```

would load my big data file into the database as well. Is this possible? How can I make this happen? If not, can anyone think of a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task?rq=1

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Rake arguments are painful to pass around, unfortunately (and [`db:seed`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L185) doesn't pass its arguments through, regardless).

Your best bet is to use environment variables to pass your extra args through:

```
rake db:seed minimal=yes
```

and

```
unless ENV["minimal"]
  # do stuff
```

etc

Comment: Beauty. Worked perfectly. Thanks.