# How to seed a new database in Rails 4, when user creates a new subdomain account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can use *rake db:seed* to seed an existing database. However, in a multitenant app, using subdomains, how could I seed data for a new user account?

Should I not use seed.rb, but create seeded data with a migration?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters as illustrated here: [Can I pass an argument to rake db:seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450434/can-i-pass-an-argument-to-rake-dbseed)

Then you can use switch and if statements to load/change either the data or use a different connection.