# rails rake task - access to command line arguments variable names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, rake, command-line-arguments, variable-names

Ok, I have the following task,

```
namespace :test do
  task :a do |t,args|  
    p ENV.keys
  end 
end

$ rake test:a ARG1 = "me" ARG2 = "my wife"
```

The above command displays a big array i.e ENV.keys

`ENV.keys` looks like this,

```
["MANPATH", "SSH_AGENT_PID",........,"BUNDLE_BIN_PATH", "RUBYOPT", "ARG1", "ARG2"]
```

I want only "ARG1" and "ARG2" and I dont want "MANPATH","RUBYOPT" and other things. (Not "me" and "my wife").

The command line variable names. Not values.

Help?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task for passing command line arguments to rake task

Comment: I checked it. It doesn't answer my question!

Comment: Sorry I thought you were interested in the values and not the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
namespace :test do
  task :a, [:param_me, :param_wife] do |t, args|  
    p args.param_me
    p args.param_wife
  end 
end

$ rake "test:a[me, my wife]"
```

You will only need double quotes if you have spaces in your parameters.

Comment: I was not trying that way because, I have a comma in my parameters like, "me" "my wife" "my second, third and fourth wife". Note the comma in between second and third. That comma wont work with [this, way].