# Figuring out how rake works and how command line arguments can be handled in a rake tasks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

How can I pass arguments to a rake task so that it executes the rake task on a different schema? For example I have rake code such as the one below:

```
namespace :update_persons_table do
  task :import => :environment do

  config   = Rails.configuration.database_configuration
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = "my, public, data_master_reports"  

       # do stuff make updates to table....

  end
end
```

I call this rake task from the command line like this:

```
RAILS_ENV='production' rake update_persons_table:import
```

BTW, does the above RAILS_ENV call I am using have to do with the `:environment do` statement I am using in the second line? Because in my database.yml file i do have a `production:` database entry. Im trying to figure out how the whole plumbing for this works. This rake task updates a table in a database. But I want to be able to call it on another clone table in a different database. How can I do that with passing parameters in the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task

Comment: No I am asking for the plumbing of how rake tasks work with database environments. I want to use the same rake task to load the data into another table in another database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I pass arguments to a rake task so that it executes the rake task on a different schema?

I think what you are asking is

> How can I pass arguments to a rake task so that it executes the rake task on a different environment?

The `schema` is the same for all environments of your app

> does the above RAILS_ENV call I am using have to do with the :environment do statement I am using in the second line?

Yes `:environment do` will take whatever environment(:development, :test, :production) you are  specifying. In your example, its `RAILS_ENV='production'`

Now to run the rake task in a different environment, like say the development environment

```
`RAILS_ENV='development' rake update_persons_table:import'
```

Now the same code that was executed on the production environment db when you ran `` `RAILS_ENV='production' rake update_persons_table:import' `` has been run in the development environment db

Hope this is clear enough to get you started