# Testing a rake task with passed parameters in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

In rspec, i want to test a rake task with some parameters passed in, so in the command line you would run this:

```
rake commissions:create_price_points options=1,2,3
```

and in the rake task i use ENV['options'].

In my rspec I have

```
rake = get_rake_environment(RAKE_FILE)
rake["commissions:create_price_points"].invoke(options=1,2,3)
```

This runs the rake fine but this, and other attempts that I've made with invoke and execute, do not pass the options into it. Just wondering if anyone has any insight on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: using environment variables for rake tasks is not the default way. you can add it to the rake calls directly like rake commissions:create_price_points[1,2,3] please go and read the docs.

Answer (score 4):

The arguments passed to the `invoke` method are not the same as those passed in the rake command line.  In RSpec, which is Ruby, the expression `options=1,2,3` assigns the array `[1,2,3]` to the local variable `options` and passes that array to `invoke`. When received by the `invoke` method, the array is treated as a formal argument to the rake task.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/825832/1008891 for more information on this approach.)

Since your rake task is expecting the environment variable `options` to be set, you need to set that prior to invoking it, as in:

```
ENV['options'] = '1,2,3'
```