# How to invoke rake with non-rake parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, erd

I have a rake task that creates diagrams:

```
task :diagram do
  `rake erd filetype=dot disconnected=true`
end
```

The execution of this task is quite slow and I guess it is because in the nested rake-invoke statement the whole rails environment is loaded again.

I wanted to use `Rake::Task['...'].invoke` instead. But the `erd` task has some non-rake arguements (`filetype=dot` etc.), which don't seem to work with the `invoke` method.

Is there a way to pass those arguments to rake so that I can use the proper rake invoke syntax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5050412/784318 gave me some pointers towards environment varables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `ENV` variables in your code:

```
task :diagram do
  ENV['filetype']='dot'
  ENV['disconnected'='true'

  Rake::Task['erd'].invoke
end
```

Comment: This does the trick. It saves me valuable 7.7 seconds each time.