# How to pass arguments to mina deploy tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment

We are using [Mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/) to deploy our Rails4 app after switching from Capistrano. On cap we could do `cap production deploy:invoke task="namespace:taskname"` where invoke task was a custom deploy task that took arguments to execute a specified rake task on a given environment.

How to pass arguments to mina to run specified rake tasks?
So far the closest to argument passing in mina I have seen is `mina deploy to=staging`. 
I am looking for usage close to `mina invoke namespace:taskname` that would cd into app's /current directory and do a `bundle exec rake namespace:taskname`.

This seems simple enough, what am I missing?

**Edit**
As per Guy Teube's suggestion in /config/deploy.rb I now have

```
set :task, ENV['TASK']
set :current, "#{deploy_to}/current"

desc "Invokes a raketask"
task :invoke => :environment do
  queue "cd #{current} && bundle exec rake #{task}"
end
```

Running `mina invoke TASK=old:votes --simulate` does not work yet, outputs "`cd /home/deployer/apps/manabalss/current && bundle exec rake`"
(Notice the string terminating without TASK environmental variable not having been taken into account.

Comment: Latest mina has rake task support built right in. Use `mina rake[namespace:task]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it dawned on me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5050412/3319298), mina is essentially rake and it is possible to simply:

```
rake mytask var=foo
p ENV['var'] # => "foo"
```

Then there is no need for a `set:` line, just use the environmental variable as-is.
This mina task expects an environmental variable "task".

```
desc "Invokes a raketask"
task :invoke => :environment do
  queue! "cd #{current}"
  queue! "bundle exec rake #{ENV['task']} RAILS_ENV=production"
end
```

Then just call it with:

```
mina invoke task=namespace:taskname
```

If specifying the deployment environment is needed, modify the task to

```
queue! "bundle exec rake #{ENV['task']} RAILS_ENV=#{ENV['to']}"
```

And call with

```
mina invoke task=namespace:taskname to=staging
```

Answer (score 3):

Long time, but I will leave my cent.

Maybe simply creating one mina task for each rails task you need on the server.
In my case I needed to provide the team with something as simple as:

```
mina deploy_prod
and 
mina deploy_beta
```

To do this I`ve created these tasks outside deploy block:

```
task :deploy_prod => :environment do
  set :rails_env, 'production'
  set :branch, 'master'
  set :deploy_to, '/var/www/site'
  @command_valid = true
  invoke :deploy
end

task :deploy_beta => :environment do
  set :rails_env, 'development'
  set :branch, 'dev'
  set :deploy_to, '/var/www/site_beta'
  @command_valid = true
  invoke :deploy
end
```

And this inside deploy block, to make sure everyone will choose among above tasks:

```
to :before_hook do
  unless @command_valid
    puts "usage: mina [deploy_prod|deploy_beta] [-v]"
    exit 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting use of :before_hook, may come handy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an environment variable you use when you call mina in your terminal. You could do:

```
$ mina deploy TASK=namespace:taskname
```

Of course you need to edit your `deploy.rb` to get and the `TASK` param with `ENV['TASK']`.

By example, I can specifiy a branch and a domain to `mina` when I deploy with this command :

```
$ mina deploy DOMAIN=1.2.3.4 BRANCH=my_specific_branch
```

With in my `deploy.rb` :

```
set :user, 'my_app'
set :domain, ENV['DOMAIN']
set :identity_file, ENV['IDENTITY_FILE']

set :deploy_to, '/home/app'
set :repository, 'git@github.com:foo/bar.git'
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] || 'master'
```

Comment: Ok, this is a start! I edited my question to show what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

if the requirement is to deploy to different environments then have a look at https://github.com/endoze/mina-multistage multi-stage plugin for mina