# rake command parsing options after --

Tags: ruby, bash, rake

As per "[How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task#answer-19466362)" I thought the following would work.

```
$ rake command -- other options
```

However the invocation fails with an `invalid option` error. The answer states:

> note the `--`, that's necessary for bypassing standard rake arguments.

It doesn't work for me. Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using `key=value` syntax works. So to set options use this.

```
$ rake command option= key=value
```

Which gives you arguments in the command.

```
args = ARGV.grep(/=/).map{ |s| [ *s.split(/=/), true ][0, 2] }.to_h
# => { "option" => true, "key" => "value" }
```

Or simpler for just keys.

```
args = ARGV.flat_map{ |s| s[/(\w+)=/, 1] }.compact
# => [ "option", "key" ]
```