# Passing parameters to Rake

Tags: ruby, powershell, rake

I have seen the popular post on how to [pass parameters to rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task).  I copy pasted sample code from that post and it is not working for me:

Rakefile.rb:

```
require 'rake'

task :my_task, [:arg1, :arg2] do |t, args|
  puts "Args were: #{args}"
end
```

Then at the command line I run

rake my_task[1,2]

Error

> rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'my_task[1'

It looks like the comma is truncated. It may need to be escaped, but I don't know how.  I tried `rake my_task[1\,2]` and it only added a slash to the error.  The answer has over 700 upvotes so...what am I doing wrong?

rake --version : 
rake, version 10.3.2

I'm using Console2 shell which says "Windows PowerShell" when I launch a new terminal instance.

Comment: What shell are you using? Try quoting the argument to Rake: `rake 'my_task[1,2]'`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - I tried `cmd` and it works fine.  So its definitely my shell.  When I switch between the two modes "Console2 and PS" both say "Windows Powershell".  And your way worked!  If you put this as an answer I will mark it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell is probably interpreting the argument to Rake as something special, so quote it to avoid that from happening:

```
rake 'my_task[1,2]'
```