# Why is ENV["HOME"] nil in my rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rake, unicorn

I have a rake task that gets called from a controller - actually the controller calls a bash script, which calls a rake task. We do this so staff can request a database import, which reimports the data and restarts the app.

At command line, it works. `ENV['HOME']` is set.

However, when we call it via the controller -> bash script, the rake task claims it is nil.

So, what could be causing this? Shouldn't `$HOME` always be visible?

UPDATE:

the controller (via unicorn web server) calls a bash script like so: `system("#{Rails.root}/lib/cron/manual_digest.bash")` in the bash script that gets called, i ran `export -p` and got:

```
declare -x BUNDLE_BIN_PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle"
declare -x BUNDLE_GEMFILE="/var/www/ma_staging/releases/20150319193546/Gemfile"
declare -x BUNDLE_ORIG_MANPATH="/var/www/ma_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/man"
declare -x GEM_HOME="/var/www/ma_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0"
declare -x GEM_PATH=""
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x MANPATH="/var/www/ma_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/man"
declare -x OLDPWD="/var/www/ma_staging/current"
declare -x OLD_PID="/var/www/ma_staging/shared/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"
declare -x PATH="/var/www/ma_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
declare -x PID="/var/www/ma_staging/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
declare -x PWD="/home/deploy/ma_staging/current"
declare -x RACK_ENV="staging"
declare -x RAILS_ENV="staging"
declare -x RUBYLIB="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib"
declare -x RUBYOPT="-rbundler/setup"
declare -x SHLVL="2"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x UNICORN_FD="12,13"
declare -x _ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH=""
```

running this same command via a rails console:

```
export BUNDLE_BIN_PATH='/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle'
export BUNDLE_GEMFILE='/var/www/ma_staging/releases/20150319193546/Gemfile'
export BUNDLE_ORIG_MANPATH='/var/www/ma_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/man'
export COLUMNS='213'
export GEM_HOME='/var/www/ma_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0'
export GEM_PATH=''
export HOME='/home/deploy'
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LESSCLOSE='/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
export LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
export LINES='50'
export LOGNAME='deploy'
export MAIL='/var/mail/deploy'
export MANPATH='/var/www/ma_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/man'
export OLDPWD='/home/deploy/ma_staging/current/lib'
export PATH='/var/www/ma_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games'
export PS1='\u:\W\$ '
export PWD='/home/deploy/ma_staging/current'
export RAILS_ENV='staging'
export RUBYLIB='/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib'
export RUBYOPT='-rbundler/setup'
export SHELL='/bin/bash'
export SHLVL='1'
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK='/tmp/ssh-jkdbX19657/agent.19627'
export SSH_CLIENT='68.82.90.217 38992 22'
export SSH_CONNECTION='55.55.55.55 3322 55.55.55.55 22'
export SSH_TTY='/dev/pts/0'
export TERM='xterm'
export USER='deploy'
export _='/usr/local/bin/bundle'
export _ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH=''
```

I looked into "restricted shells" but that doesn't quite explain what I'm seeing, with variables missing. I also looked into "subshells" (since the first output is `SHLVL=2`) but that also does not specifically explain this behavior.

I'm looking for some documentation or something somewhere that says "when you do X, the variables for $HOME and $USER are not set because Z"

I am suspecting something with unicorn, but have not found anything to explain why these variables would be empty.

Comment: Update: the rake task *is* running as the expected user whe I view PS output

Comment: How does the controller execute the script? How does the script execute the rake task? What commands/etc. **exactly**?

Comment: @EtanReisner i updated my original question with more info

Comment: Does unicorn itself see `HOME`/etc.? I'm going to assume it doesn't and that it is running itself in an intentionally cleaned environment so when it spawns the sub-shell (`/bin/sh` most likely from `system` though that might run `bash` if there's a shebang line on the script I'm not sure) it also doesn't have those variables available. But this is just speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, turns out the issue was with the way unicorn was being started up and our suoders config file, which was misconfigured. I was worried it was some bug - nope, just misconfiguration on our end.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `echo "USER: $USER"` to your bash script to see what user controller is running under.  User's can be created without a home directory so this is probably what you're running into.  For example, user `apache` for the Apache www server has no home directory.

You could also set environment in the bash script.  If `$HOME` is not set you could set it to `/tmp`??

Comment: Interesting; when I try to do `ENV['USER']` it also is `nil` how is that even possible?

Comment: Not sure on that one..Maybe try checking out the service for controller?? '/etc/init.d' entry.  It might help with clues as to what is going on.. I think checking for $HOME in your bash script and setting and alternate if it's not defined is the best route.

Comment: Yes, we've managed to bypass the issue in another way - but we have no idea why it is behaving this way, and setting $HOME manually, while it would work, is more a hack than a fix. I'm sure there's some logical explanation of some sort for what we're seeing, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Although running rake task though controller is a bad idea but still this is how you can run it and get access to all your env. variables. Give it try

```
system "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd #{Rails.root.to_s} && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake task_namespace:it_might_work --silent'"
```

Also, You can pass agruement to rake task in case if above thing failed. Refer [How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

Btw, i strongly recommends to put this rake task as background script. Use it `sidekiq` or `delayed_job` etc.

Comment: ok, i gave this a go; still no dice. the variables available via `export -p` did not change, even after stopping/starting unicorn