# How to pass an option to a Rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, command-line-arguments, rakefile

I would to know if it was possible to pass an option from the commande line to the task without having the Rakefile taking option for itself.

Here is my task:

```
task :task do
 args = ARGV.drop(1)
 system("ruby test/batch_of_test.rb #{args.join(' ')}")
 args.each { |arg| task arg.to_sym do ; end }
end
```

Here is the command I want to be functional:

```
rake task --name test_first_one
```

The result I want is the same as this:

```
ruby test/batch_of_test.rb --name test_first_one
```

For this code, I get this error:

```
invalid option: --name
```

How can --name (or another option) can be passed to my task ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments to a rake task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

Comment: No, I read it at least two times. My problem is related to passing options and not exactly arguments... (with "--" or '-' ).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cannot add flags to Rake tasks. I think the closest syntax available is using `ENV` variables.

```
rake task NAME=test_first_one
```

Then in your task:

```
name = ENV['NAME']
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
task :task, [args] => :environment do |t, args|
 system("ruby test/batch_of_test.rb #{args.join(' ')}")
 args.each { |arg| task arg.to_sym do ; end }
end
```

and you call it like this.

```
rake task[args]
```

---

UPDATE

```
task :task, [:options] => :environment do |t, args|
 arg = args[:options].pop
 options = args[:options] 
end
```