# passing argument to rake task in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arguments, rake

I am trying to execute multiple rake tasks in a single task. 
All of the rake tasks are used to update the columns of respective tables.
For example
if health_post_id >100000
Delete that record

Now i need to pass 100000 as an argument through the command line .But I am not able to figure that out
Here is the code

```
if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
 namespace :clear_data do


  desc 'clear time slots'
  task :clear_time_slots => :environment do
    TimeSlot.where('health_post_id > ?', p).each do |time_slots|
      time_slots.destroy
    end
  end

  desc "Clean the Practices table"
  task :clear_practice_records => :environment do
      Practice.where('health_post_id > ?', p).each do |practices|
        practices.destroy
      end
  end


  desc "clean database"
  task :clear_database => :environment do |p|
    Rake::Task['clear_data:clear_practice_records'].execute
    Rake::Task['clear_data:clear_time_slots'].execute


    end



 end
 end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments to a rake task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

Comment: I wish it was that easy for a beginner

Comment: can somebody please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure, but I guess you should be able to do:

```
if Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?
 namespace :clear_data do
  desc 'clear time slots'
  task :clear_time_slots, [:post_id] => :environment do |_, args|
    TimeSlot.where('health_post_id > ?', args[:post_id]).destroy_all
  end

  desc "Clean the Practices table"
  task :clear_practice_records, [:post_id] => :environment do |_, args|
    Practice.where('health_post_id > ?', args[:post_id]).destroy_all
  end


  desc "clean database"
  task :clear_database, [:post_id] => :environment do |_, args|
    max = args[:post_id]
    Rake::Task['clear_data:clear_practice_records'].execute(post_id: max)
    Rake::Task['clear_data:clear_time_slots'].execute(post_id: max)

    #OR

    #Rake::Task['clear_data:clear_practice_records'].invoke(max)
    #Rake::Task['clear_data:clear_time_slots'].invoke(max)
  end
 end
end
```