# Rake task loading in Working Directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

So I have a pretty simple rake task, it looks like such:

```
#Clean User
 desc "Wipes User"
 task :clean_user, [:emp] => :environment do |t, args|
 Core::User.find(args[:emp]).destroy
end
```

Simple right? Essentially it takes in a ID and wipes the user. So I run the rake task as `bundle exec rake clean_user 123`

The 123 is just any sample number, however the weird thing is the error I get back, which essentially says:

> "Error could not find user with ID = *My Working Directory Path*"

Of course replace *My Working Directory Path* with /usr/me/documents/folders/etc....

This makes no sense? It's like it's not taking in the actual 123 number? Are my arguments setup wrong for taking in Parameters from Command Line?

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task?rq=1 for how to add command line parameters to rake tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rake task arguments are not passed like that on the command line. Try this:

```
bundle exec rake clean_user[123]
```

Comment: Yup that was it, can't believe it was that simple!