# OptionParser::MissingArgument

Tags: ruby, rake

I want to create a rake task that takes one parameter with no argument.

```
task :mytask => :environment do
  options = Hash.new
  OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.on('-l', '--local', 'Run locally') do
      options[:local] = true
    end
  end.parse!

  # some code

end
```

But it throws:

```
$ rake mytask -l
rake aborted!
OptionParser::MissingArgument: missing argument: -l
```

Meanwhile:

```
$ rake mytask -l random_arg
ready
```

Why?

---

- Rake 10.4.2
- jruby 1.7.13

Comment: I'm not sure OptionParser is the best plan here. `rake` already has its own option parsing and a method for passing in data with `VAR=value` at the end, like here `LOCAL=1` would work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task) for examples.

Comment: @tadman I want to have my option as flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do commit to this approach you need to separate your task's arguments from `rake`'s own arguments:

```
rake mytask -- -l
```

Where `--` means "end of main arguments" and the rest are for your task.

You'll need to adjust your argument parsing to trigger only on those particular arguments:

```
task :default do |t, args|
  # Extract all the rake-task specific arguments (after --)
  args = ARGV.slice_after('--').to_a.last

  options = { }
  OptionParser.new do |opts|
    opts.on('-l', '--local', 'Run locally') do
      options[:local] = true
    end
  end.parse!(args)

  # some code
end
```

Going about it this way is usually really messy and not very user friendly, so if you can avoid it and employ some other method that's usually better.

Comment: Rake ignores my argument that way

Comment: That's how it seems to work historically, but you're right, that doesn't seem to work in newer versions of `rake`.

Comment: I've added a version here that focuses specifically on those custom arguments.