# Testing a Rake task that uses OptionParser with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I have a Rake (12.0) task that uses `OptionParser` to get an argument.

The task looks like

```
require 'optparse'

namespace :local do
  task :file do
    options = Hash.new

    opts = OptionParser.new
    opts.on('--file FILE') { |file|
      options[:file] = file
    }

    args = opts.order!(ARGV) {}
    opts.parse!(args)

    # Logic goes here.
    # The following is enough for this question
    String.new(options[:file])
  end
end
```

The task can be executed running `rake local:file -- --file=/this/is/a/file.ext`

Now I want to verify with RSpec that A new string is created but I don't know how to pass the file option inside the spec.

This is my spec

```
require 'rake'

RSpec.describe 'local:file' do

  before do
    load File.expand_path("../../../tasks/file.rake", __FILE__)
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end

  it "creates a string" do
     expect(String).to receive(:new).with('zzzz')
     Rake.application.invoke_task ("process:local_file")
  end
end
```

And correctly I get

```
#<String (class)> received :new with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("zzzz")
              got: (nil)
```

But if I try

`Rake.application.invoke_task ("process:local_file -- --file=zzzz")`

I get

`Don't know how to build task 'process:local_file -- --file=zzzz' (see --tasks)`

I have also tried `Rake::Task["process:local_file"].invoke('--file=zzzz')` but still `got: (nil)`.

How should I pass the option in the spec?

Thanks

Comment: I never did this so I can't comment but this looks like what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for pointing that post out. I have changed my task and now I'm able to run the spec.

Comment: You'rer welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you take the options from ARGV (the array that contains the arguments passed to the script):

```
args = opts.order!(ARGV) {}
```

you can set ARGV to contain whatever options you want before invoking Rake::Task.

For me (ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2, rspec 3.4) something like the following works

```
argv = %W( local:file -- --file=zzzz )
stub_const("ARGV", argv)
expect(String).to receive(:new).with('zzzz')
Rake::Task['local.file'].invoke()
```

(By convention, ARGV[0] is the name of the script.)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.