# Logic to test whether a command line argument to a rails rake task is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rake task that returns a count of records for a given email. The email is provided to the rake task as a command line argument, like so

```
rake stats:count email=me@gmail.com
```

But if the rake task is called *without* an email provided (i.e. `rake stats:count`), I would like helpful message to appear, like "Please provide an email"

How do I do this?

I have tried this

```
email = ENV['email']
if email.nil? puts "Please provide an email"
end
```

But it errors with `NameError: undefined local variable or method email' for main:Object`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

Comment: you don't have access to that(`email`) variable/method unless you define it in your rake task. The way to access arguments depends on how you named them in your `do |_task, args|`, in this case I named it `args`, so, in your case, let's suppose you have it like `namespace :stats do`... `task :count, [:email] => :environment do |_task, args|`. So, in your rake code you'd access `email` as `args[:email]`

Comment: You can just check `if ENV['email']` then.

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: Are you showing your whole code?

Comment: yeah, I think you need to put a little bit more of your code. Just put your task definition, add some `...` and put where you are accessing that value, then add some more `...` to hide code you don't want to show, and put the `end` to see where your rake task definition ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An argument provided to a rake task via `var=value` is accessible inside the rake task with `ENV['var']`.

If the argument is not provided, `ENV['var']` will return `nil`.

So you can simply check `ENV['email'].nil?`

i.e.

```rb
if ENV['email'].nil?
  puts "Please provide an email" 
else
  # code to run if email is provided
end
```