# How to create custom rake tasks with multiple arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to create a custom rake task with supporting multiple arguments.

When finished I want to call the rake task like:

```
rails conifg:load -i 5 -o "now" ...
```

How to create them ?

The ([rubyonrails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)) says :

```
task :task_name, [:arg_1] => [:prerequisite_1, :prerequisite_2] do |task, args|
  argument_1 = args.arg_1
end
```

But I dont understand it.

Answer (score 1):

> When finished I want to call the rake task like:
>
> `rails conifg:load -i 5 -o "now" ...`

You can't, that is not how you pass arguments to Rake tasks, those arguments (`-i`, `-o`, etc) are passed to Rake itself, not to your task.

Instead, there are a few options:

- Use [thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor) which has (in my opinion) a *far* superior API, and allows for traditional Unix style arguments (`-i`, `--help`, etc). You can easily produce a script that would be invoked with:

  ```
  thor config:load -i 5 -o "now"
  ```
- Use [Rake's argument system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task), where you would pass arguments in the form

  ```
  rails config:load[5,now]
  ```
- Build your own script, placed in `bin`. For example, `bin/config` can accept arbitrary arguments, and be invoked however you like. Any of the following are possible:

  ```
  ./bin/config load -i 5 -o now
  ./bin/load_config i=5 o=now
  ./bin/config.load 5 now
  # etc
  ```