# Run rails dev:cache with an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-5

The Rails command `rails dev:cache` toggles whether Rails caching features work in the local development environment. It does this by creating or destroying a file that acts as a flag for the features. However, for our dev setup script, I would like to run the command so that the caching features are always turned on instead of toggled.

The source code for `rails dev:cache` includes this [`enable_by_argument` function](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7c32f09c4a390aa7876dd671a3778c3034c081c4/railties/lib/rails/dev_caching.rb#L24-L32):

```rb
def enable_by_argument(caching)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p("tmp")

  if caching
    create_cache_file
  elsif caching == false && File.exist?(FILE)
    delete_cache_file
  end
end
```

**How do I run the `rails dev:cache` command so that it uses this argument?** I've tried several variations, including `rails dev:cache[true]`, `rails dev:cache\[true\]` and `rails dev:cache true`, but all of them have used the toggling behavior instead of the argument-controlled behavior.

This is not a duplicate of [How to pass command line arguments to a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task) because that question is about passing arguments to Rake tasks. But this is a command built into Rails instead.

Comment: Right now, in our script, we're checking for the existence of the file ourselves before running the command. I think it would be cleaner to avoid having to make that check if we can, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do it by default, because [the original task](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/tasks/dev.rake) does not take an argument at all.

However if we improve the task code a little bit, we can get it to do what you want.
Put this at the end of your `Rakefile`:

```
# Remove original task
Rake::Task["dev:cache"].clear

# Reimplement task with new and improved behavior
namespace :dev do
  desc "Toggle development mode caching on/off"
  task :cache, [:enable] do |task, args|
    enable = ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(args[:enable])
    if enable.nil?
      # Old behavior: toggle
      Rails::DevCaching.enable_by_file
    else
      # New behavior: by argument
      Rails::DevCaching.enable_by_argument(enable)
      puts "Development mode is #{enable ? 'now' : 'no longer'} being cached."
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can use any of these:

```
rails dev:cache
rails dev:cache[true]
rails dev:cache[false]
```